# QEMU emulating MS-DOS cannot access CD-ROM

Tags: ms-dos, cd-rom, qemu

I am using `qemu-system-i386` on a Windows 10 PC to emulate an MS-DOS system. I have installed MS-DOS 6.22 successfully from disk images from original Microsoft media.

I am starting QEMU using this command:

```
c:\program files\qemu\qemu-system-i386.exe -hda msdos.disk -m 64 -L . -soundhw sb16,adlib,pcspk -k en-gb -vga cirrus -nic user,model=pcnet -boot order=d -drive file=.\cdrom.iso,media=cdrom,index=2,if=ide,format=raw
```

`cdrom.iso` is an image created by mkisofs (running under WSL) using this command:

```
mkisofs -pad -b disks/msdos/msd622_b.img -R -J -o cdrom.iso cdrom
```

This includes an El Torito boot floppy of MS-DOS 6.22. When running QEMU with the above command, it successfully boots from CD-ROM into MS-DOS. `XDVD2.SYS` detects the CD-ROM correctly, identifying it as a QEMU virtual DVD-ROM. `MSCDEX` runs correctly and assigns the CD drive a drive letter, as illustrated:

```
SeaBIOS (version rel-1.12.0-0-ga698c8995f-prebuilt.qemu.org)


iPXE (http://ipxe.org) 00:03.0 C980 PCI2.10 PnP PMM+03F914B0+03EF14B0 C980



Booting from DVD/CD...
Starting MS-DOS...


XDVD2, 1-05-2016.   CD/DVD name is DVDROM.
IDE0 Controller at I-O address C020h, Chip I.D. 80867010h
CD0:  IDE0 Secondary-master, QEMU DVD-ROM, ATA-100.

MODE prepare code page function completed

MODE select code page function completed
MSCDEX Version 2.23
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corp. 1986-1993. All rights reserved.
       Drive D: = Driver DVDROM unit 0
A:\>_
```

However, whenever I try to access the CD - for example, with `dir d:\`, I get this error:

```
CDR101: Not ready reading drive D
Abort, Retry, Fail?
```

The QEMU virtual CD-ROM and the ISO file are both clearly valid, otherwise QEMU would not have been able to boot the El Torito image. I have repeated the test using an old Windows 95 setup boot disk that uses a different CD driver and it too fails in the same way, so this *appears* to be something specific about MSCDEX inside QEMU. I have also tried a different ISO image in case there is a problem with my ISO image, with no difference in results.

**How can I access the QEMU virtual CD-ROM from MS-DOS?**

---

For reference, here are the boot disk's startup files.

CONFIG.SYS

```
DOS=HIGH,UMB
BUFFERS=11,0
FILES=60
LASTDRIVE=H
FCBS=1,0
STACKS=0,0
DEVICE=A:\DOS\HIMEM.SYS /TESTMEM:OFF
DEVICE=A:\DOS\EMM386.EXE X=B800-C7FF I=B000-B7FF A=64 H=128 D=256 ON
DEVICEHIGH=A:\DOS\SETVER.EXE
COUNTRY=044,,A:\DOS\COUNTRY.SYS
DEVICEHIGH=A:\DOS\DISPLAY.SYS CON=(EGA,,1)
DEVICEHIGH=A:\EXTRAS\XDVD2.SYS /D:DVDROM
SET TEMP=A:\TEMP
SET TMP=A:\TEMP
```

AUTOEXEC.BAT

```
@ECHO OFF
A:\DOS\SMARTDRV.EXE /X
PROMPT $p$g
PATH A:\DOS
A:\DOS\MODE.COM CON CODEPAGE PREPARE=((437) A:\DOS\EGA.CPI)
A:\DOS\MODE.COM CON CODEPAGE SELECT=437
LH A:\DOS\KEYB.COM UK,,A:\DOS\KEYBOARD.SYS
LH A:\DOS\DOSKEY.COM /INSERT
LH A:\DOS\MSCDEX.EXE /D:DVDROM /M:20 /E
```

Comment: What happens if you boot QEMU with only `qemu-system-i386 -cdrom cdrom.iso`?

Comment: The emulated FAT formatted floppy image that MS-DOS booted off of will be drive A: Drive D: will be the ISO 9660 file system on the CD-ROM, if any. If there's no ISO 9660 file system on the CD-ROM image then you'll get errors like the one you're receiving.

Comment: @StephenKitt if I do this, then MSCDEX assigns C: to the CD-ROM drive, but I still get the error.

Comment: @RossRidge the ISO file does have a valid filesystem - I've verified this by mounting the CD as a virtual disk in Windows, and alternatively by attaching an existing, known-working, ISO image in qemu.

Comment: @RossRidge done. (Thanks to yourself and Stephen Kitt for your comments so far, BTW!)

Comment: Great documentation so far. Thanks. Usually I shun this kind of questions, but I think this might end up helpful. Can't add much except for the error message shown: CDR101 targets driver or hardware errors (CDR102 is software (usually memory access for buffers, often solved by removing /E) while CDR103 is the filesystem). So above problem arises way before any file system or image issue. On a real PC cable check would be the first step. Since it's virtual, it must be the CD driver. Maybe try to replace FreeDOS' XDVD2.SYS with some other driver?

Comment: Thinking if it, is there a reason to invoke with `-drive` instead of `-cdrom <filename>` maybe the `format=raw` parameter isn't really helpful? It's your own image anyway, isn't it?

Comment: +1 Dos emulators are within the scope of this forum. I have the same problem but did not think to ask this forum. I am looking forward to the answer.

Comment: I have almost exactly this problem with the FreeDOS install .ISO.
In my case it depends on either the host OS or host architecture. I haven't isolated which.

When I run QEMU on Raspbian on a RPi 3 B+, the CD works just fine.
Using exactly the same command line for QEMU on an x64 Windows host system, the CD is bootable, but inaccessible to the guest OS.

Comment: Have you tried replacing mscdex with shsucdx from FreeDOS? That's what I use on my "MS-DOS 6.22 on real vintage hardware" setup because it supports a wider range of ISO9660 filesystems than mscdex.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's reason to believe that this is a qemu bug (actually a problem caused by the configuration of SeaBIOS in qemu 3.0 and 3.1). If this is the case, the CD driver will work fine in qemu 2.12.1 or older (SeaBIOS will be 1.11.1 or older), or qemu 4.0.0 or newer (SeaBIOS will be 1.12.1 or newer). A qemu displaying a SeaBIOS version of 1.11.2 or 1.12.0 will not work.

Comment: You are correct - trying again with qemu 4.1.0 I got much better results. Thanks!

Comment: as of today debian 10 does provide qemu 3.1.0 which is then buggy.